# Error pages for exceptions during page rendering

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

In the backing beans of my JSF application, certain exceptions may be thrown at any time, and I want to react to this by redirecting to an error page. I have included the [omnifaces](http://omnifaces.org) FullAjaxExceptionHandler, and my `web.xml` contains

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>my.own.ResourceNotFoundException</exception-type>
    <location>/error/error404.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/error/error500.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

In most cases, including Ajax requests, this works fine: `ResourceNotFoundException` leads me to the error page. However, when the exception is thrown in a method annotaded with `@PostConstruct`, I always get the generic page for error code 500.

Is this because JSF wraps the exception in something else and the mechanism in `web.xml` does not recognize it? If yes, how can I get this to work as expected?

Here is the exception trace I see in the server log:

```
    Feb 07, 2013 11:08:32 AM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/my/projects/details/details.xhtml]
javax.el.ELException: //P:/codebase/code/portal/jsf-impl/target/classes/META-INF/resources/common/title.xhtml: Bei der Ressourcen-Einspeisung auf dem verwalteten Bean projectDetailsController ist ein Fehler aufgetreten.
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:90)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:302)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:309)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.CompositeRenderer.encodeChildren(CompositeRenderer.java:78)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at my.own.filters.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:48)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.__invoke(StandardHostValve.java:151)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at my.own.UTF8Valve.invoke(UTF8Valve.java:34)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:269)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Bei der Ressourcen-Einspeisung auf dem verwalteten Bean projectDetailsController ist ein Fehler aufgetreten.
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:229)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:105)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:71)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:147)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstDeferredExpression.getValue(AstDeferredExpression.java:44)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstCompositeExpression.getValue(AstCompositeExpression.java:50)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase$AttributesMap.get(UIComponentBase.java:2362)
    at com.sun.faces.el.CompositeComponentAttributesELResolver$ExpressionEvalMap.get(CompositeComponentAttributesELResolver.java:345)
    at javax.el.MapELResolver.getValue(MapELResolver.java:52)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.writeText(ELText.java:227)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextComposite.writeText(ELText.java:150)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:85)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderException
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokeAnnotatedMethod(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:119)
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokePostConstruct(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:99)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:223)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokeAnnotatedMethod(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:117)
    ... 68 more
Caused by: my.own.ResourceNotFoundException: Did not find project
    at my.own.projects.details.ProjectDetailsController.createModel(ProjectDetailsController.java:198)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your log suggests, `ResourceNotFoundException` is wrapped in four other exceptions.

You could develop your own CustomExceptionHandler like the one in [Duke's Forest example](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glnpw.html) instead of using omnifaces FullAjaxExceptionHandler or even extend it and go down causes until you reach `ResourceNotFoundException` then use `NavigationHandler` to redirect to the desired error page.

Here is edited version of related classes and faces-config.xml from Duke's Forest example. This should work as you expect even if the exception occurs in `@PostConstruct` method:

CustomExceptionHandlerFactory.java

```
package com.forest.exception;

public class CustomExceptionHandlerFactory extends ExceptionHandlerFactory {
   private ExceptionHandlerFactory parent;

   // this injection handles jsf
   public CustomExceptionHandlerFactory(ExceptionHandlerFactory parent) {
       this.parent = parent;
   }

    @Override
    public ExceptionHandler getExceptionHandler() {

        ExceptionHandler handler = new CustomExceptionHandler(parent.getExceptionHandler());

        return handler;
    }

}
```

CustomExceptionHandler.java

```
package com.forest.exception;

public class CustomExceptionHandler extends ExceptionHandlerWrapper {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(CustomExceptionHandler.class.getCanonicalName());
    private ExceptionHandler wrapped;

    CustomExceptionHandler(ExceptionHandler exception) {
        this.wrapped = exception;
    }

    @Override
    public ExceptionHandler getWrapped() {
        return wrapped;
    }

    private boolean includesResourceNotFoundException(Throwable t) {
        if(t == null) {
            return false;
        else {
            return t instanceof ResourceNotFoundException || includesResourceNotFoundException(t.getCause());
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void handle() throws FacesException {

        final Iterator<ExceptionQueuedEvent> i = getUnhandledExceptionQueuedEvents().iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            ExceptionQueuedEvent event = i.next();
            ExceptionQueuedEventContext context =
                    (ExceptionQueuedEventContext) event.getSource();

            // get the exception from context
            Throwable t = context.getException();

            final FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            final Map<String, Object> requestMap = fc.getExternalContext().getRequestMap();
            final NavigationHandler nav = fc.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();

            //here you do what ever you want with exception
            if(hasResourceNotFoundException(t) {
                try {
                    //log error ?
                    log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Critical Exception!", t);

                    //redirect error page
                    requestMap.put("exceptionMessage", t.getMessage());
                    nav.handleNavigation(fc, null, "/error/error500?face-redirect=true");
                    fc.renderResponse();
                } finally {
                    //remove it from queue
                    i.remove();
                }
            }
        }
        //parent hanle
        getWrapped().handle();
    }
}
```

faces-config.xml (partial)

```
<factory>
        <exception-handler-factory>
            com.forest.exception.CustomExceptionHandlerFactory
        </exception-handler-factory>
</factory>
```

Comment: A custom exception handler was indeed what we used in the end, but the approach is rather crude, since the exception is hard-coded into the handler. I guess the underlying problem is that the exact exception stack produced by JSF is somewhat unpredictable, so we can only search for some known cause...